# How can I See the content of a MultipartForm request?

Tags: java, apache, scala, httpclient, multipartform-data

I am using Apache HTTPClient 4. I am doing very normal multipart stuff like this:

```
val entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("filename", new FileBody(new File(fileName), "application/zip").asInstanceOf[ContentBody])
entity.addPart("shared", new StringBody(sharedValue, "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

val post = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);
post.setEntity(entity);
```

I want to see the contents of the entity (or post, whatever) before I send it. However, that specific method is not implemented:

```
entity.getContent() // not defined for MultipartEntity
```

How can I see what I am posting?

Comment: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity - contains getContent() from documentation - http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html

Comment: yes, and this function is not implemented. it will give you a NotImplementedException

Answer (score 18):

Use the `org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity` [writeTo(java.io.OutputStream)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html#writeTo(java.io.OutputStream) method to write the content to an `java.io.OutputStream`, and then convert that stream to a `String` or `byte[]`:

```java
// import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
// import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
// ...
// MultipartEntity entity = ...;
// ...

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(entity.getContentLength());

// write content to stream
entity.writeTo(out);

// either convert stream to string
String string = out.toString();

// or convert stream to bytes
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
```

Note: this only works for multipart entities small enough to be read into memory, and smaller than 2Gb which is the maximum size of a byte array in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Following would help for sure:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
httpEntity.writeTo(content);
logger.info("Calling "+url+" with data: "+content.toString());
```

The above has a fix in comparison to the first answer, there is no need to pass any parameter to ByteArrayOutputStream constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not know the content? Although, you are building the `StringBody` by supplying `sharedValue`. So, how could it be different than `sharedValue`.

Comment: because the full multipart form request is different than the sum of the string body contents. theres wrappers for the data, and i want to see all that shit

Comment: There is another common use case for this: automated logging. I came upon this question because I log every interaction by simply sending the `HttpRequestBase` to a logging infrastructure that extracts the `HttpEntity` (if extant), etc. and logs it.

Answer (score 0):

I have printed the Multipart request by following code, You can try like

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

entity.writeTo(bytes);

String content = bytes.toString();

Log.e("MultiPartEntityRequest:",content);
```

Comment: This doesn't really add any more information than the existing answers, particularly the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10408206).

Comment: this was more readable and easy on the eyes. I appreciate when hard-to-read code specially when you are in a hurry to understand is made concise.